# Sign into a site with Google on HTMLUnit in Java

Tags: java, wordpress, google-chrome, authentication, htmlunit

I'm trying to make a Java program that logs into a Wordpress site that uses Google accounts to sign in. My code is this:

```
package autoLogin;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlButton;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlDivision;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.HTMLParserListener;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.AbstractJavaScriptEngine;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

        webClient.setJavaScriptEngine((AbstractJavaScriptEngine<?>) new JavaScriptEngine(webClient));
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        webClient.getCache().setMaxSize(0);
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);

        HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://maclab.gameful.me/signin");



        HtmlDivision ContWithGoogle = (HtmlDivision) page.getHtmlElementById("nsl-custom-login-form-main");
        //page = (HtmlPage)ContWithGoogle.click();

        System.out.println(page.asText());

    }
}
```

The issue is that the Wordpress only allows Google accounts to sign in but the webpage that I get returned in Java doesn't seem to match the one I open in Chrome even with a completely clean version of chrome with no account signed in. Is there something I'm missing? How do I sign into a site that requires you to "Sign in with Google"?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVMNJ.jpg

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but do you already know Selenium? In Selenium you can use the Chrome Browser directly. (Not sure if your problem would be solved using Selenium)

Comment: I might try Selenium again. I've been using HTMLUnit cause I was having some errors with Selenium on my Mac for some reason. Might make a StackOverflow post for that error then heh.